# Why can i only display one tag per newsitem?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables 2 of them have a many to many relationsip. The third one is a junction table.

```
newsitem:
id    content
1     "content1"
2     "this is content2"


newsitem_tags:
newsitem_id  | tag_id
   1         |   1
   1         |   2

tags
id   |  name
 1   |  "Computer"
 2   |  "Health"
```

I have more entries, but this is just a example.

I have a page where i display all the newsitems with the tag "Computer" with this query:

```
      $sql = "SELECT newsitem.content,
      newsitem.title,
      newsitem.id,
      group_concat(tag.name ORDER BY  tag.name) as tags,
      newsitem_tag.tag_id FROM newsitem
      LEFT JOIN newsitem_tag ON newsitem.id = newsitem_tag.newsitem_id
      LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = newsitem_tag.tag_id
      WHERE newsitem.deleted=0 and tag.deleted=0 and newsitem_tag.tag_id=1";
```

Every newsitem i show on the page has multiple tags. I try to display the tags in every news item with this php code:

```
$result= $conn->query($sql);
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
<?php echo $row["tags"] ?></h6>
}
```

The thing is. All the right news items display that have the tag "computer". But the news items only display one tag: "computer". As you can see some newsitems do have 2 or more tags.

Why aren't the rest of the tags being displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you can alleviate this problem by moving the logic in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    newsitem.content,
    newsitem.title,
    newsitem.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name ORDER BY tag.name) AS tags,
    newsitem_tag.tag_id
FROM newsitem
LEFT JOIN newsitem_tag
    ON newsitem.id = newsitem_tag.newsitem_id AND newsitem_tag.tag_id = 1
LEFT JOIN tag
    ON tag.id = newsitem_tag.tag_id AND tag.deleted = 0
WHERE
    newsitem.deleted = 0;
```

If this works, it means that some of your `WHERE` logic was filtering off entire records.  Note that we can leave the check on `newsitem.deleted` in the `WHERE` clause, since it *will* filter off records wherever we put it.